# OrientDB graph query that match specific relationship

Tags: sql, graph, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am developing an application using OrientDB as a database. The database is already filled, and now I need to make some queries to obtain specific information.

I have 3 classes and 3 edges to be concerned. What I need to do is query the database to see if some specific relationship exists. The relationship is like this:

```
ParlamentarVertex --Realiza> TransacaoVertex --FornecidaPor> EmpresaFornecedoraVertex AND ParlamentarVertex --SocioDe> EmpresaFornecedoraVertex
```

The names with a vertex in it are a vertex of course, and the arrows are the edges between the two vertexes.

I've tried to do this:

```
SELECT TxNomeParlamentar, SgPartido, SgUF FROM Parlamentar where ...

SELECT EXPAND( out('RealizaTransacao').out('FornecidaPor') ) FROM Parlamentar
```

But I do not know how to specify the relationships after the where clause.

I've also tried to use match

```
MATCH {class: Parlamentar, as: p}  -Realiza-> {as:realiza}
```

But I am not sure how to specify the and clause that is really important for my query.

Does anyone have some tip, so I can go in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

I've managed to use the query below:

```
SELECT EXPAND( out('RealizaTransacao').out('FornecidaPor').in('SocioDe') ) FROM Parlamentar
```

It almost works, but return some relationships incorrectly. It looks like a join that I did not bind the Pk and FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing here is to use a MATCH as follows:

```
MATCH 
  {class:ParlamentarVertex, as:p} -Realiza-> {class:TransacaoVertex, as:t} 
       -FornecidaPor-> {class:EmpresaFornecedoraVertex, as:e},
  {as:p} -SocioDe-> {as:e}
RETURN p, p.TxNomeParlamentar, p.SgPartido, p.SgUF, t, e
```

(or RETURN whatever you need)

As you can see, the AND is represented as the addition of multiple patterns, separated by a comma

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I will try this solution and get back to you.